org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [int arg0] in constructor
I'm migrating our tests from Junit4 to Junit5, one of which is a base test class that's been inherited by 29 other classes with a constructor.
I changed it to use Junit5, the structure is like below:
public class BaseTest {
    protected String field1;
    protected Integer field2;

    public BaseTest(String field1, Integer field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}


public class ChildTest extends BaseTest {
    public ChildTest(String field1) {
        super(field1, null);
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> data() {
        return Stream.of(Arguments.of("string1"));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("data")
    public void test1() {
        assertNull(this.field2);
    }
}


But now, it throws
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String arg0] in constructor [public junit5.ChildTest(java.lang.String)].

I saw the other answers which don't really apply here, anyone could share any ideas please?
I saw this one: Junit 5 - No ParameterResolver registered for parameter

I'm only using one annotation: @ParameterizedTest already;
I tried to use setup() annotated with @BeforeEach, but somehow Junit5 doesn't allow me pass in params into it...

Thanks!

With JUnit Jupiter parameterized tests are passed to method arguments, not to the class' constructor. Having said that, it's kind of hard to help you with this example - you're aserting the value (null) of a field of the test itself, which doesn't seem very useful. Can you share a more accurate example of what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps even your original JUnit 4 test, or some simplified version thereof?

Yes, that's my understanding as well: parameterize test arguments instead of constructor, but https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection says possible. This is an oversimplified example, but reproduces the error I'm faced with.
